# In MySQL Concept "Check CONSTRAINTS" is Not Working. Following are my Table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table demo (
    ID int,
    Name varchar(255),
    age int,
    CONSTRAINT CHK_DEMO CHECK (age>=18)
);
```

But When I Insert values in Table like this

```
mysql> insert into demo (ID,Name,age) value ('5', 'DON',15);
```

OUTPUT IS:

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: Correct.  MySQL does not implement `check` constraints.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html):

```
 - CHECK

The `CHECK` clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines. See Section 1.8.2.3, “Foreign Key Differences”.
```

This is also true of the explicit `constraint` definition as well.

In other words, MySQL supports the *syntax* of check constraints.  But, MySQL does not actually implement them.  They do nothing.

Comment: Sorry..! But I can not Understand..!

Comment: @SachinfromPune mysql is like a naughty child. Tell them "collect your toys from the floor". They say "will do" - they understand what you mean by it - but then do nothing. The solution is to stop using such a childish database and use a mature solution such as PostgreSQL